# Does my thought experiment adequately address quantum entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, probability, determinism

My friend and I (both still undergraduates) were discussing philosophy. He is a fairly strong supporter of determinism, and I am still trying to find out my opinion. So in the spirit of good-natured debate, I’ve taken the burden of proof and claimed that he’s wrong.

His argument (I probably wont do it justice) is as follows:

If you had an unreasonably powerful computer that could know everything in the universe, then you could predict accurately the past/present/future. The fundamental randomness that is observed in quantum mechanical models is irrelevant because the properties of larger structures i.e. atoms are emergent and we are able to accurately describe their behavior.

My counter-argument (based on a shaky self read understanding of QFT/QM) is the following thought experiment:

Suppose an advanced civilization could create black holes. Lets say they send 3 black hole making devices to various parts of a galaxy. There they each perform the double slit experiment with a single photon. Depending on where the photon lands within the interference pattern, e.g. in a high probability or low probability location a device will either create a black hole or not. My hypothesis is because where the photon lands is up to probability you could only state the probability of the outcomes and no 100% accurate prediction could be determined.

I realize that this may be unnecessarily complicated. My attempt here is to show that although trajectories, rates of decay, and other things can be calculated and predicted with a high degree of accuracy, results in the large scale world, can be entangled with results off small scale phenomena and are therefore not deterministic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107363/discussion-on-question-by-stefan-does-my-thought-experiment-adequately-address-q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does my thought experiment adequately address quantum entanglement?

No. Quantum entanglement requires measuring correlations between  separated entangled objects. Nowhere have you stated that the BH making devices are entangled or the measurements being compared.

> So in the spirit of good-natured debate, I’ve taken the burden of proof and claimed that he’s wrong

As per our current understanding of nature, a non-deterministic model of the universe is our best guess or that other guesses are no better. So your claim is right.
 However nobody knows how the universe *actually* behaves-t'Hooft for eg believes in a fundamentally computer like universe-deterministic with simple laws. Up untill Bell, one thought it didn't matter.

> My hypothesis is because where the photon lands is up to probability you could only state the probability of the outcomes....I realize that this may be unnecessarily complicated.

The unpredictability of where the photon would land is by itself enough to dispute determinism. You did complicate it.

Your hypothesis is correct but your friend's point is finer:  was complete information about the system known? 
You should extend you argument by stating: Yes it was: we knew all the properties of the source, the photon the slits and the screen. We also knew where and when the photon is initially. Yet we couldn't predict its trajectory.

In a line, its unpredictability **inspite** of omniscience.

> My attempt here is to show that although trajectories, rates of decay, and other things can be calculated and predicted with a high degree of accuracy,...

If a theory  can calculate an observable as accurately as it can be measured, does the underlying understanding matter?
Yes its satisfying to know how something happens. The underlying understanding also motivates new and further theoretical exploration, but from a practical standpoint, if you are in arbitrarily good agreement with the experimentalists, a 'theory of stacked turtles' is as good as any.

> ...results in the large scale world, can be entangled with results off small scale phenomena and are therefore not deterministic.

There exist large scale phenomena that result from "entangling with results of small scale phenomena". We don't use entangle in modern physics in this sense. Perhaps what you mean are emergent phenomenon.

Anyways, all macroscopic phenomenon may be fundamentally explained from microscopic behavior. That in itself doesn't rule out determinism.e.g. properties of an ideal gas,Brownian motion etc. Infact large scale observations of microscopically quantum phenomenon can appear deterministic-thats Bohr's correspondense pricnciple.

The fact there exist macrosocpic phenomemon which exhibit non-classical properties, behaviour only hitherto though to occur at atomic scales, leaves no room for any determinism. Superfluids, superconductors, bose einstein condesates, fractional hall effect, topological solids are some of the exotic ones. Radioactivity, frustrated total internal reflection, tunneling diode etc less so.

*Caution*: After all that is said and done, keep in mind that hard line claims in science have a habit of not aging well.

Comment: This is a phenomenal response thank you, I do have some caveats however. Firat off, as many have pointed out my use of entanglement is incorrect. I think what I was meaning to say is that because the decision to create a black hole is dependant on the results of the single photon experiment, until an observer checks to see if the black hole is created the device would be also be in a superposition of having created a black hole or not. Additionally your caution is one I intend to head, my attempt here was to put the burden of proof back into my friends court not to disprove determinism.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct as we understand things today, although your experiment is not directly related to entanglement. Quantum uncertainty is inherent in nature, it is not down to "hidden variables" and a lack of computing power.

Another example of this is the three-body problem. Minute quantum uncertainties in the position and momentum of each get magnified over time so that, no matter how carefully you measure the initial state, your predictions of the three orbits will get worse and worse as you look further ahead. Even though the orbits are emergent, we cannot accurately predict them.

However that does not stop some physicists seeking such hidden variables. But they do have to contend with the existence of quantum entanglement, which is on your side here because it demonstrates conclusively that reality is "nonlocal". Any deterministic hidden variables must therefore also be nonlocal. The sum-over-histories approach to QM, together with Relativity, suggest that such nonlocality must embrace all of both space and time. That is, without knowing every last detail of the entire history of the Universe - future as well as past - deterministic prediction remains impossible.

As far as science is concerned, that makes determinism a metaphysical concept.

Of course, not everybody agrees with that, especially those who cling to determinism precisely because they are trying to avoid metaphysics.

Comment: *"Quantum uncertainty is inherent in nature, it is not down to 'hidden variables'"* that is merely a political view of many scientists, it is not itself a scientific fact. It is actually an anti-scientific view, because science presupposes that all effects are explicable in terms of physical variables.

Comment: You quote my words out of context: it very much is "as we understand things today". See my following remarks, where I elaborate: "However that does not stop...". And thank you for providing my first example of "not everybody agrees with that", even if only because you did not read it through properly.

Comment: *Who* understands things that way? *Scientists* have not ceased to understand things in terms of variables. The uncertainty in QM is only shown to be related to (known methods of) *measurement*, not to the physical mechanisms themselves.

Comment: @Steve I think you're missing the "hidden" part of "hidden variables". The phrase "hidden variables" means something quite specific, and theories based on local hidden variables were proven to be inconsistent with measurements, using Bell's inequality. Nonlocal hidden variable theories were not ruled out (see e.g. de Broglie-Bohm mechanics), but those have other issues, especially in terms of extending to quantum field theory.

Comment: @probably_someone, what are the alternatives then besides nonlocal hidden variables? Or is that the only credible mechanism known to science?

Comment: @Steve There are four possibilities technically allowed by Bell's inequality: local non-determinism (i.e. ordinary quantum mechanics), nonlocal hidden-variable theories (i.e. Bohmian mechanics), nonlocal non-determinism (which is just kind of awful, and I don't know of any theories that throw away both assumptions), and superdeterminism (a loophole in which, among other things, the experimenter's brain itself is nontrivially correlated with the quantum system they're measuring). Of these, the one that has the fewest problems is ordinary quantum mechanics.

Comment: @probably_someone, I'd suggest that "ordinary QM" (really we just mean the non-scientific elements of the Copenhagen interpretation) suffers from the worst defect of all, namely that an indeterminate system is intractable to any science (it's not exactly clear how even QM works within that understanding, if it describes a system which is said to follow no rules).

Comment: @Steve "Non-deterministic" $\neq$ "is said to follow no rules".

Comment: @probably_someone, to be honest I'm not exactly clear how a non-deterministic system even works (although perhaps that's the point), or how the concept itself is characterised. Indeed I can't even see any clear reason why physicists have resorted to it, when deterministic explanations remain.

Answer (score 0):

You are right; the universe is fundamentally stochastic. This is one of the things quantum mechanics has taught us. But QM has also taught us that we cannot possibly know everything about the universe. The uncertainty principle is a fundamental character of nature: We cannot simultaneously know a particle’s position and momentum to arbitrary precision, for example. Therefore, no matter how powerful a computer you have, it can never have all the data it needs to predict the future exactly. *In principle*, it can only know an approximation of the state of things.

Now, your friend is right that the Law of Large Numbers is a powerful concept in physics. But in these quasi-philosophical discussions, we cannot neglect the difference between *fundamental* determinism and *apparent* determinism. If all you are talking about is whether, *practically*, you could pretty much predict the future of macroscopic-scale things with a big computer, then you could. We do that on a smaller scale all the time. But you would not be predicting the future on *all* scales because doing so is impossible. That is what you would need for *fundamental* determinism, and that is what I think you are really talking about in your debate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107362/discussion-on-answer-by-gilbert-does-my-thought-experiment-adequately-address-qu).